# iOS - blur and buggy retina graphics on older devices running iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been developing an app for **iPad** and was testing i on iPad 3 and iPad air with no problems at all. When i tried same app on **iPad 2** the images were blur and some of them were not displaying properly even some were half visible half not visible.

As per my knowing the **iOS7** only apps do not need **non-retina** graphics so i am using only Retina Graphics. So i tried using **Asset Catalog** too but same was the result.

Strangely when i use **image@2x.png** in **xib** it displays fine but do not show image in **xib** and when i use image.png it is displayed in xib but same issue when run on the device.

What i need to do to show images in xib too and would run fine on device?

Comment: For best results on non-retina devices I would include both resolutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisrt You MUST provide non-retina graphics in the asset catalog. You should understand that bigger images on old devices provides bigger memory and performance  impacts. 
 
You must pay attention also on odd measure, because if some geometric frames calculation results in decimal point such as 23.5 1.5 you are going to have antialiased elements in your interfaces.
You can avoid that wrapping frames into CGRectIntegral.

Comment: you can provide the same image for both the assets, but I think you'll find similar issues. I don't think that Apple stated that you can't include non-retina assets, this probably fine only for iPhone app because there aren't non-retina iphone that can handle iOS7.